# Xamarin image doesn't showing in phone

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use xamarin.forms and I am trying make image. I tried so many things but icon doesn't showing in phone.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ArduinoNotes
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ArduinoNotes.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem
            Text="a"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <StackLayout>
        <Image x:Name="mainImage"
               Source="icons/logo.png"
               WidthRequest="50"
               HeightRequest="50">
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCkaC.png)

I tried writing source as logo.png, icons.logo.png and ArduinoNotes.icons.logo.png(ArduinoNotes is my project name).

Comment: "I tried so many things" - did you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)?  There are examples for both local images stored in each platform project, and embedded resources stored in the shared project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want to display a local image. I want to give some suggestions here.

One easy way for iOS is put your image in the ProjectName.iOS/Resources folder. Also you could create a new folder in Resources and put image in this folder. Then set the Build Action of the image to **BundleResource**. Then we could just use it such as:

```
<Image x:Name="mainImage" BackgroundColor="Pink"
     Source="icons/monkeyface.png"
     WidthRequest="50"
     HeightRequest="50">
```

In iOS, we also should consider [Safe Area Layout Guide on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout). (Because when I debugger,I found my image was in safearea so i cannot see it) We could set

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
     ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
     ....
     >
```

For Android, put image in ProjectName.Android/Resources/drawable folder and set the Build Action to **AndroidResource**. (However since now we could not create a subfolder in drawable)Then use it:

```
<Image x:Name="mainImage" BackgroundColor="Pink"
     Source="monkeyface.png"
     WidthRequest="50"
     HeightRequest="50">
```

Hope it works for you.